# Mysql-python install error asking for command line tools on mac

Tags: python, mysql-python

```
    Running MySQL-python-1.2.5/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /tmp/easy_install-lkPuJx/MySQL-python-1.2.5/egg-dist-tmp-W1ZChm
In file included from _mysql.c:44:
/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.7.17/include/mysql/my_config.h:172:9: warning: 'SIZEOF_LONG' macro redefined [-Wmacro-redefined]
#define SIZEOF_LONG      8
        ^
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7/pymacconfig.h:54:17: note: previous definition is here
#        define SIZEOF_LONG             4
                ^
In file included from _mysql.c:44:
/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.7.17/include/mysql/my_config.h:177:9: warning: 'SIZEOF_TIME_T' macro redefined [-Wmacro-redefined]
#define SIZEOF_TIME_T    8
        ^
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7/pymacconfig.h:57:17: note: previous definition is here
#        define SIZEOF_TIME_T           4
                ^
2 warnings generated.
_mysql.c:287:14: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'Py_ssize_t' (aka 'long') to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
                cmd_argc = PySequence_Size(cmd_args);
                         ~ ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
_mysql.c:317:12: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'Py_ssize_t' (aka 'long') to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
                groupc = PySequence_Size(groups);
                       ~ ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
_mysql.c:470:14: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'Py_ssize_t' (aka 'long') to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
                        int j, n2=PySequence_Size(fun);
                               ~~ ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
_mysql.c:1127:9: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'unsigned long' to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
                len = mysql_real_escape_string(&(self->connection), out, in, size);
                    ~ ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
_mysql.c:1129:9: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'unsigned long' to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
                len = mysql_escape_string(out, in, size);
                    ~ ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
_mysql.c:1168:9: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'Py_ssize_t' (aka 'long') to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
        size = PyString_GET_SIZE(s);
             ~ ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7/stringobject.h:92:32: note: expanded from macro 'PyString_GET_SIZE'
#define PyString_GET_SIZE(op)  Py_SIZE(op)
                               ^~~~~~~~~~~
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7/object.h:116:56: note: expanded from macro 'Py_SIZE'
#define Py_SIZE(ob)             (((PyVarObject*)(ob))->ob_size)
                                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~
_mysql.c:1178:9: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'unsigned long' to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
                len = mysql_real_escape_string(&(self->connection), out+1, in, size);
                    ~ ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
_mysql.c:1180:9: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'unsigned long' to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
                len = mysql_escape_string(out+1, in, size);
                    ~ ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
_mysql.c:1274:11: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'Py_ssize_t' (aka 'long') to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
        if ((n = PyObject_Length(o)) == -1) goto error;
               ~ ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7/abstract.h:434:25: note: expanded from macro 'PyObject_Length'
#define PyObject_Length PyObject_Size
                        ^
_mysql.c:1466:10: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'unsigned long' to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
                        len = strlen(buf);
                            ~ ^~~~~~~~~~~
_mysql.c:1468:10: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'unsigned long' to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
                        len = strlen(buf);
                            ~ ^~~~~~~~~~~
_mysql.c:1504:11: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'unsigned long' to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
                                len = strlen(buf);
                                    ~ ^~~~~~~~~~~
_mysql.c:1506:11: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'unsigned long' to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
                                len = strlen(buf);
                                    ~ ^~~~~~~~~~~
13 warnings generated.
ld: library not found for -lssl
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
error: Setup script exited with error: command 'cc' failed with exit status 1
```

This is the error when I try to download MySQL-python

I tried uninstall command line tools and download, I see request coming to ask for command line tools.

This is the error:

```
xcode-select: note: no developer tools were found at '/Applications/Xcode.app', requesting install. Choose an option in the dialog to download the command line developer tools.
error: Setup script exited with error: command 'cc' failed with exit status 1
```

Please help me with this.

Comment: Thanks @Luke woodward

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fixed by using :

```
env LDFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include 
-L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib" pip2.7 install mysql-python
```

Comment: It worked. Should be marked as a solution.